# android app with like button functionailty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an android app in which users can like and unlike an image. The problem I am facing is that when the user loads the images the first time when app launches, I want to show the already liked images as colored, in Instagram the images I have liked earlier are colored when I load image. How can I do this feature in my app ?

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder>  {


    private String imageUrl;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader,imageLoader1;
    private Context context;
    String Load;
private static ClickListener c;
    public static final String uu = "uu";
    String number;

    public static final String UserNum = "UserNum";
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    private String[] pos;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;
    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String url,imgoffset;
    //testing from a real server:
    private static final String LIKE_URL = "http://svastek.in/insta/like.php";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes1;
    //List of superHeroes

    List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    public CardAdapter() {
    }

    public CardAdapter(List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes, Context context) {
        super();
        //Getting all the superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        superHeroes1= superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
        sharedPref  =context.getSharedPreferences(UserNum, 0);
        number =  sharedPref.getString(uu, "");

    }


    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;



    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        SuperHeroes superHero = superHeroes.get(position);
       Log.d("position", String.valueOf(position));
        Log.d("url", superHero.getImageUrl());
       // Load = superHero.getImageUrl();
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
        imageLoader1 = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader1.get(superHero.getProurl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.thumbNail, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        Log.d("i am ob", "ob");
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.thumbNail.setImageUrl(superHero.getProurl(), imageLoader1);
        holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
        holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));

      if(superHero.getstat())
     {
          Log.d("i am g","g");
         Log.d("i am value", String.valueOf(superHero.getstat()));
            holder.like.setImageResource(R.drawable.plike);
        }
       else
       {
          Log.d("i am p","p");
            holder.like.setImageResource(R.drawable.glike);
        }



        // holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);
        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("i m in like","i m in like");
          SuperHeroes superHero = superHeroes.get(position);
        Load = superHero.getImageUrl();
    Log.d("like position", String.valueOf(position));
              new LikeIt().execute();
            if(dudo!=null) {
                Log.d("i m in like1", "i m in like1");
                dudo.onlike(v, position);


            }}        });


    }

public void refresh(List<SuperHeroes> superHeroes){
    Log.d("Refresh","Refresh is called ");
    this.superHeroes=superHeroes;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }






        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            public NetworkImageView imageView;
          public CircularNetworkImageView thumbNail;
            public TextView textViewName;
            public TextView textViewuserName;
            public TextView textViewRank;
            public ImageButton like;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_row);
            //textViewuserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_row);
            textViewRank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
            thumbNail = (CircularNetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            like = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_like);
         //   itemView.setOnClickListener( this);




        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (dudo != null) {
                Log.d("i m in like1", "i m in like1");
                dudo.onlike(v, 2);
            }
        }
    }


    class LikeIt extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag

             int success;

            String Imgurl = Load;
            Log.d("request like url!", Imgurl);

          //  try {
                // Building Parameters
                HashMap<String, String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Params.put("Imgurl", Imgurl);
           Params.put("user", number);


                Log.d("request!", "starting");


                String encodedStr = getEncodedData(Params);

                //Will be used if we want to read some data from server
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                //Connection Handling
                try {
                    //Converting address String to URL
                    URL url = new URL(LIKE_URL);
                    //Opening the connection (Not setting or using CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    //Post Method
                    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    //To enable inputting values using POST method
                    //(Basically, after this we can write the dataToSend to the body of POST method)
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                    //Writing dataToSend to outputstreamwriter
                    writer.write(encodedStr);
                    //Sending the data to the server - This much is enough to send data to server
                    //But to read the response of the server, you will have to implement the procedure below
                    writer.flush();

                    //Data Read Procedure - Basically reading the data comming line by line
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String line;
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Read till there is something available
                        sb.append(line + "\n");     //Reading and saving line by line - not all at once
                    }
                    line = sb.toString();           //Saving complete data received in string, you can do it differently

                    //Just check to the values received in Logcat
                    Log.i("custom_check","The values :");
                    Log.i("custom_check", line);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if(reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();     //Closing the
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Same return null, but if you want to return the read string (stored in line)
                //then change the parameters of AsyncTask and return that type, by converting
                //the string - to say JSON or user in your case
                return null;
            }

        }
    private String getEncodedData(Map<String,String> data) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String key : data.keySet()) {
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = URLEncoder.encode(data.get(key), "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(sb.length()>0)
                sb.append("&");

            sb.append(key + "=" + value);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted

            }


private  static ClickListener dudo ;
  public interface ClickListener{
       void onlike(View v,int pos);



    }
    public void setClickListener(ClickListener dudo){
        this.dudo=dudo;
        Log.d("i m in interface","i m in interface");
    }
        }
```

I have database tables storing the users id that have liked the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution using inbuilt sqlite db.